# Create a container on android with an app running inside it

Tags: java, android, kotlin, containers, docker-container

The idea is to create a secure messaging app for Android smartphone.
One security goal is to have the app running inside a container.
I have so far been unsuccessful in finding a way to create a container on Android without using a paid service like a MDM.

Any help as to wether its possible and how would be much appreciated.

I have researched a lot on the internett on how to do this but haven't come over anything yet.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

A container on Android is essentially a secure environment that isolates the app and its data from other apps and the underlying operating system. Creating a container on Android can be challenging and requires a deep understanding of the Android security architecture.

One approach to create a container on Android is to use Android's built-in system APIs, such as the Android Work Profile, which allows creating a separate, isolated profile on the same device. However, this approach still requires a management solution such as an MDM to enforce the security policies on the app.

Another approach is to create a virtualized environment using virtualization software like QEMU, which allows running a separate instance of Android on the same device. This approach provides a high degree of isolation and security, but can be complex to set up and manage.

In summary, creating a container on Android to run a secure messaging app is possible but requires a deep understanding of Android security architecture and the use of specialized tools and management solutions.